# Missing prototype in my practice arithmetic quiz program, and almost every other program I make

Tags: c

Yesterday I was able to make a program (ASCII converter etc etc) that had the same problem [ Every function had a missing prototype error when I build the program ] I was able to fix it through random trial and error having no idea how I did it. Here's my arithmetic quiz practice program. I also tried  putting int initialize(),clear(),exit(),additionquiz(),subtractionquiz(),divisionquiz(),multiplicationquiz(); and it still gave me a missing prototype.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    /* Main Menu */
    int numbers[10];
    int main()
    {
        while(1==1)
        {
            int choice;
            initialize();
            printf("Arithmetic Quiz Program\n");
            printf("1 - Addition\n2 - Subtraction\n3 - Multiplication\n4 - Division\n5 - Exit\n");
            scanf("%d",&choice);
            if(choice==1)
            {
                clear();
                additionquiz();
            }
            else if(choice==2)
            {
                clear();
                subtractionquiz();
            }
            else if(choice==3)
            {
                clear();
                multiplicationquiz();
            }
            else if(choice==4)
            {
                clear();
                divisionquiz();
            }
            else if(choice==5)
            {
                exit();
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%cPlease choose a number from 1 - 5",7);
                clear();
                continue;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    /* For clearing the page */
    int clear()
    {
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<25;i++)
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    /* Assigns the array */
    int initialize()
    {
        numbers[0]=6;
        numbers[1]=0;
        numbers[2]=2;
        numbers[3]=5;
        numbers[4]=3;
        numbers[5]=1;
        numbers[6]=9;
        numbers[7]=4;
        numbers[8]=7;
        numbers[9]=8;
        return 0;
    }
    /* addition quiz */
    int addition()
    {
        int a,diff,b,answer,choice;
        a=0;
        diff=1;
        b=a+diff;
        while(1==1)
        {
            if(a>9)
            {
                a=0;
                diff++;
            }
            if(b>9)
            {
                b=0;
            }
            if(diff>9)
            {
                diff=0;
            }
            printf("%d + %d = ",number[a],number[b]);
            scanf("%d",&answer);
            if(answer==number[a]+number[b])
            {
                printf("\nCORRECT!!!\n");
                a++;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\nWRONG!!!\n");
                clear();
                additionquiz();
            }
            printf("\nWhat do you want to do next?\n1 - Answer another addition Question\n2 - Go back to main menu\n3 - Exit program\n");
            scanf("%d",&choice);
            if(choice==1)
            {
                clear();
                additionquiz();
            }
            else if(choice==2)
            {
                clear();
                main();
            }
            else if(choice==3)
            {
                exit();
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%cPlease choose a number from 1 to 3",7);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    /* The subtraction quiz */
    int subtraction()
    {
    int a,diff,b,answer,choice;
        a=0;
        diff=1;
        b=a+diff;
        while(1==1)
        {
            if(a>9)
            {
                a=0;
                diff++;
            }
            if(b>9)
            {
                b=0;
            }
            if(diff>9)
            {
                diff=0;
            }
            if(numbers[a]-numbers[b]<0)
            {
                a++;
                subtraction();
            }
            printf("%d - %d = ",numbers[a],numbers[b]);
            scanf("%d",&answer);
            if(answer==numbers[a]-numbers[b])
            {
                printf("CORRECT!!!\n\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("WRONG!!!\n\n");
                clear();
                subtractionquiz();
            }
            printf("\nWhat do you want to do next?\n1 - Answer another subtraction Question\n2 - Go back to main menu\n3 - Exit program\n");
            scanf("%d",&choice);
            if(choice==1)
            {
                clear();
                subtractionquiz();
            }
            else if(choice==2)
            {
                clear();
                main();
            }
            else if(choice==3)
            {
                exit();
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%cPlease choose a number from 1 to 3",7);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    /* multiplication quiz */
    int multiplicationquiz()
    {
    int a,diff,b,answer,choice;
        a=0;
        diff=1;
        b=a+diff;
        while(1==1)
        {
            if(a>9)
            {
                a=0;
                diff++;
            }
            if(b>9)
            {
                b=0;
            }
            if(diff>9)
            {
                diff=0;
            }
            printf("%d * %d = ",number[a],number[b]);
            scanf("%d",&answer);
            if(answer==number[a]*number[b])
            {
                printf("\nCORRECT!!!\n");
                a++;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\nWRONG!!!\n");
                clear();
                multiplicationquiz();
            }
            printf("\nWhat do you want to do next?\n1 - Answer another multiplication Question\n2 - Go back to main menu\n3 - Exit program\n");
            scanf("%d",&choice);
            if(choice==1)
            {
                clear();
                multiplicationquiz();
            }
            else if(choice==2)
            {
                clear();
                main();
            }
            else if(choice==3)
            {
                exit();
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%cPlease choose a number from 1 to 3",7);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    /* Division quiz */
    int divisionquiz()
    {
        int a,diff,b,answer,choice,remain;
        a=0;
        diff=1;
        b=a+diff;
        while(1==1)
        {
            if((numbers[a]<numbers[b])||numbers[b]==0)
            {
                a++;
                clear();
                divisionquiz();
            }
            if(a>9)
            {
                a=0;
                diff++;
            }
            if(b>9)
            {
                b=0;
            }
            if(diff>9)
            {
                diff=0;
            }
            printf("%d % %d = \n",numbers[a],numbers[b]);
            printf("What is the whole number?\n");
            scanf("%d",&answer);
            printf("What is the remainder? (0 if none\n)");
            scanf("%d",&remain);
            if(answer==numbers[a]/numbers[b] && remain==numbers[a]%numbers[b])
            {
                printf("\nCORRECT!!!");
                a++;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\nWRONG!!!");
                clear();
                divisionquiz();
            }
            printf("\nWhat do you want to do next?\n1 - Answer another division Question\n2 - Go back to main menu\n3 - Exit program\n");
            scanf("%d",&choice);
            if(choice==1)
            {
                clear();
                divisionquiz();
            }
            else if(choice==2)
            {
                clear();
                main();
            }
            else if(choice==3)
            {
                exit();
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%cPlease choose a number from 1 to 3",7);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You didn't define nor declare your functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exit` is an external function and you need to include its header at the top of your source code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>   // exit
```

Please notice that in the function call the addition function is called `addition` and in the function definition `additionquiz`. Same for the substraction.

For the other functions, you should declare them before you call them: that is before the `main` function definition.

```
int initialize(void);
int clear(void);
int additionquiz(void);
int subtractionquiz(void);
int divisionquiz(void);
int multiplicationquiz(void);

int main(void)
{
    /* ... */
```

Note that declaring all the functions in one go like this:

```
int initialize(void), clear(void), additionquiz(void),
    subtractionquiz(void), divisionquiz(void), multiplicationquiz(void);
```

is permitted but it is not very readable and may surprise the reader.

Finally, if these functions are not called from another source code, you should tell the reader (and the compiler) by adding a `static` specifier at the beginning of the declaration like this:

```
static int clear(void);  // the function is only called in this source code
```

Comment: Yes, I once inherited some code that mixed declarations of local variables and functions, e.g. `int var1, func1(float), var2, var3, func2(char, char);`.  That was certainly surprising.

Comment: Thanks man! will note the <stdlib.h> part! Didn't know that before

Comment: @vincentbelkin I added an edit: I see sometimes you name your function  `addition` and sometimes `additionquiz`. This could also get you some confusing compiler errors.

Comment: Oh, must have typed it wrong.. I kinda got confused with all the typing cause I'm just starting to learn programming. Sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

The C compiler works from top-to-bottom.  It must know that your functions exist *before* you attempt to call them.  So you have two choices:

1. **Define** your functions *above* `main` (i.e. move the entire function bodies).
2. **Declare** your functions *above* `main`.  i.e. put `int initialize();`, etc. above `main`.

Note also that in C, `int initialize()` is different to `int initialize(void)`.  You should be using the second version.

Comment: So i have to put (void) if it doesnt require an argument right?

Comment: @vincentbelkin: You should do, yes.

Comment: @vincentbelkin You don't _have_ to, an empty argument list says the function takes an unspecified number of arguments of unknown type, so you _should_.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Yep, I was very careful to say "should" rather than "must"!

Comment: Yeah, it was a response to the OP's inquiry "So I have to...", with a bit of elaboration, I just forgot to ping initially.

Comment: Thanks Oli! I finally get it now

Answer (score 1):

More information on what the guy above me just said can be found here. This page gives you an overview of how to suppress or enable different kinds of warnings in your code:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Also another tip. You wrote a couple while loops in your code with this syntax:

```
while (1==1)
{
    ...
}
```

this will do the same thing

```
while(1) 
{

}
```

Here's why: A while loop, an if statement, else statement, and an else if statement will
all perform the code beneath them if the code inside the parenthesis is true. Since 1 in C is true and 0 is false, my while loop above works the same as yours.

Answer (score 0):

First, learn to compile with all warnings enabled and with debugging information (e.g. with `gcc -Wall -g` on Linux). Then improve your program till no warnings are given by the compiler (trust the compiler).

Then, learn to have a declaration for each of your function. Start your sole source file with them, or, if you have several source files, make a header file with them.

So you could add just after your `#include` lines:

```
// clear the screen
void clear(void);

// initialize the numbers
int initilize(void);

// addition quiz
int addition(void);

// subtraction quiz
int subtraction(void);

// multiplication quiz
int multiplicationquiz(void);

// division quiz
int divisionquiz(void);
```

By the way, your functions might be better named, and you could have formal arguments in them (else use `void` as the argument list). And I don't understand why they all return an `int` which you don't use.